# Integer in Elasticsearch printed as string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.4. After declaration of index template with one interger field:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9201/_template/template_1?pretty' -d'
{
  "template": "te*",
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "aaa": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

and putting to this index a document with number as **string**:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9201/template_1/type1/1?pretty' -d'
{
    "aaa" : "3"
}
'
```

I receive as a search result:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9201/template_1/_search?pretty=true?q=*:*'
...
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [ {
          "_index" : "template_1",
          "_type" : "type1",
          "_id" : "1",
          "_score" : 1.0,
          "_source" : {
            "aaa" : "3"
          }
        } ]
      }
```

Why `aaa` field is not printed as integer (without quotes) as declared in index template? This field is definitely integer because when I try to assign some characters to `aaa` there is an exception. But this search result looks confusing and I don't know if Elasticsearch made there implicit conversion to integer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_source` field contains **raw** document. During processing Elasticsearch automatically converts the field's value to integer and then index. Thus the index contains integer representation of the value whereas raw document contains string value.